# Most/more efficient way to query an object's class/type

Tags: r, performance, optimization

Is there a more efficient way to query an object's class than using a `class(get(...))` combination?

```
envir <- new.env()
## --> to illustrate the generic `get(<id>, <from>)` case

assign("x", 10, envir)
class(get("x", envir, inherits = FALSE))
```

I'm guessing that `get()` is implemented "as fast as possible" anyway, but I thought that in certain circumstances (e.g. extremely large objects) the *get* operation would generate too much overhead and that there might be some C/C++ kung fu that could be applied?

What lead me to believe that this might be possible is the way `makeActiveBinding` stores away invisible information in some [C objects](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/455a5a12396dde27bd0f03097d5478d4bfa3bf19/src/main/envir.c#L3147) (AFAIU). Thus, the "class-only" information might live there somewhere as well and could be queried in a "stand-alone" manner.

Comment: Have you tried any speed tests (via `microbenchmark`, perhaps) against alternative code? I rather doubt the size of `x` matters -- I tried your code with `assign("x",1:1e8,envir)` and got zeroes back from `system.time(class(....))`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: thanks a lot for replying. No, haven't done any actual benchmarks yet. Was just a quick question that came to mind.

Comment: What about `vapply(envir, class, character(1L))` or `eapply(envir, class)` The latter is the environment version of `lapply`, iterating over the objects in an environment